# ワードプレスで、特定の更新者の記事を記事一覧から省きたいです！

Tags: wordpress

特定の更新者が最後に更新した記事を、記事の一覧から省きたいと思っています。
下記の最後の行のような形で、著者ではなく、更新者を省きたいのですが、どなたかお力をお借りできないでしょうか。

```
array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'modified_author'=> '-2',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メインループであれば下記のようになるかと思います。

```
function custom_query($query)
{
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('post')) { //条件は適宜
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_edit_last',
                    'value' => array(), //対象の投稿者IDを配列で
                    'compare'=>'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_query');
```

WP_Queryをnewする場合はargsにmeta_queryをセットします。